# Do multiple return to battlefield effects "stack"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature I control without flying has a coin counter from [Athreos, Shroud-Veiled](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAthreos%2c%20Shroud-Veiled%5d) dies, and I have [Luminous Broodmoth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLuminous%20Broodmoth%5d) and Athreos on the field.  What happens?

Do I only get the original creature back? With or without flying counter? Does this cause me to get a copy of the creature since both cards say return to battlefield?

Answer (score 6):

Both Athreos and Broodmoth's abilities create a triggered effect ("Whenever ...") when the creature dies. As the controller of the effects, you choose the order in which they go on the stack.

Whichever effect resolves first (the second one you put on the stack) finds the card it's looking for and returns it to the battlefield, with a flying counter if it was Broodmoth's effect.

The second effect to resolve looks for the card, can't find it in the zone it expects it to be in (because it's already been returned to the battlefield) and fizzles.

Or in other words: you get one creature back, with your choice as to whether it has a flying counter on it or not. As an aside at this point, you're *never* going to get a copy of something unless an effect explicitly says "create a copy" or similar.

Comment: Athreos can put coins on opponents creature. Would it be any different in your opponent controls Athreos? I would expect the active player, other player order, meaning Athreos ability would resolve first, and your opponent would get your creature.

Comment: If you pick Luminous Broodmoth's ability to use, does it still have a coin counter on it?

Comment: @Richard Correct. Triggers are put on the stack in APNAP order (603.3b), so if the Athreos is controlled by your opponent and the creature dies on your turn, Athreos's trigger will resolve first and Broodmoth won't do anything.

Comment: @nick012000 No, the counter disappears the moment the creature leaves the battlefield (122.2), so it certainly won't exist when it returns.